# Install OpenSSL 1.0.2 in /opt/local on MacOS

Tags: macos, openssl, osx-elcapitan

I have an installed version of `openssl 0.9.8zg` in `/usr/bin/openssl`. However I need to have a version of `openssl 1.0.2` in `/opt/local`. I was trying to update the version in `/usr/bin/openssl` and then move to `/opt/local`, but since I am using `El Capitane` I cannot access `/usr/bin`. How can I install an upgraded openssl in the given directory?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a package manager that uses /opt/local, but the easiest may be to make symlinks there from a `brew` install, or you could build openssl from source using the `--prefix=/opt/local` configure option, i.e....

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local
make
make install
```